# Copy a texture from BlendDataTextures via Python

Tags: python, scripting

How to copy a texture from `bpy.data.textures`

```
# Assuming it has a texture in bpy.data.textures

textures = bpy.data.textures
new_texture = textures[0].copy()
name = textures.new("", new_texture.type).name
textures[name] = new_texture
```

and it raise error

```
TypeError: bpy_prop_collection[key]: invalid key, must be a string or an int, not str
```

Is there a way to duplicate that texture, or need to set all the attributes to the new texture?

Comment: The line `textures[0].copy()` already creates a duplicate and pushes it into `bpy.data.textures`

Comment: Thank you, I got it, Turns out I didn't find it added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `textures[0].copy()` already creates a duplicate and pushes it into `bpy.data.textures`

```
textures = bpy.data.textures
t = textures[0].copy()
t.name = "new-texture-duplicate" # if you want to rename it
print(t.name)
```